# MD Ripple Button Fails to Open Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design

I was making a CSS button and wanted to add the Material Design ripple or wave effect to it. I found an easy script on codepen and it works great by applying the class "ripple" to any element like div, button, image, link and etc. It seems to work great except for some reason it won't actually open the link applied to the button I've made. I'm not a jquery or javascript expert but I'm guessing it has to do with the js. When I remove the "ripple" class from the button the link works fine, but when it's added the button fails to launch the link even if the ripple animation works fine.

Any help on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated thanks. The codepen demo I'm using can be found here [Material Design Ripple Buttons](http://codepen.io/Craigtut/pen/dIfzv)

Hmmm... I get that you're saying it needs to be one or the other, but not sure I quite understand the your explanation. I can get it to open the link in the original or "same" window by removing the target="_blank" but I was kind of hoping to be able to have the target option without both tabs opening the new link if that's possible.

```
(function (window, $) {

  $(function() {


$('.ripple').on('click', function (event) {
  window.location = $(this).attr('href');
   /* event.preventDefault(); */

/*HTML Button Code*/
<div class="media__body tagline overtext"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="media-btn-bottom-blue ripple" target="new">Learn More</a></div>
```

Comment: you are preventing the default behaviour of a link - you can try to remove this line `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as ochi pointed out you have to remove the line `window.location = $(this).attr('href');` from your code.

Example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOYrmx (clicking on the left login button should open google.com in a new tab)

Comment: Ohhh now I see... it appears my block comments weren't in the proper format when I was testing earlier. Was using /* event.preventDefault(); */

And I had no idea that it needed to be like so with the 2 slashes //event.preventDefault();

Like I mentioned before, I'm no JS expert.

Thank you guys, have have been a great help.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of the link is prevented by this line `event.preventDefault();`

Try adding this at the end of the `click` handler:

`window.location.href=$(this).data('href'); // **`

** Assuming the link has an `data-href` attribute, as in

`<a href="#" data-href="http://www.google.com"class="ripple" >Login</a>`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.ripple').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $div = $('<div/>'),
      btnOffset = $(this).offset(),
      xPos = event.pageX - btnOffset.left,
      yPos = event.pageY - btnOffset.top;

    $div.addClass('ripple-effect');
    var $ripple = $(".ripple-effect");

    $ripple.css("height", $(this).height());
    $ripple.css("width", $(this).height());
    $div
      .css({
        top: yPos - ($ripple.height() / 2),
        left: xPos - ($ripple.width() / 2),
        background: $(this).data("ripple-color")
      })
      .appendTo($(this));

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $div.remove();
    }, 2000);

    //add this
    alert($(this).attr('href'));

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="media__body tagline overtext">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="media-btn-bottom-blue ripple" target="_blank">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I kind of figured that would be the line to fix in the script. It opens the link now but for some reason it's opening the link in both tabs. I had set it to open target blank or new for a new tab but both tabs go to the link now.

    

`<div class="media__body tagline overtext"><a href="#" class="media-btn-bottom-blue ripple"  target="_blank">Learn More</a></div>`

Comment: @user2407463 which both tabs? you need to show more of your code then to see what's going on - you can edit your question and add your code

Comment: Sorry, still not used to the way commenting and coding on here. Both tabs meaning the page where the button is. When clicked it opens a new tab or browser window to the link but the link also opens on the page where the button was. Usually when you click a link or button you can make it open a new window to the link while the window with the original link doesn't change.

Comment: @user2407463 no worries, the reason that happens is because the default behaviour of a link is to open (in the new tab, given it's target="_blank") and then we are adding the location code at the end. In that case, you should do only one of the two steps (either prevent the default behaviour and add the location yourself - or don't add it and let the default behaviour occur)

Comment: @user2407463 if you have found your answer, mark it as such and upvote all other useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

I've extended Craig Tuttle's CodePen to also work with fixed position buttons. by adding the class of ripple-fixed to the element. Also ported it to ES6 so that it can be imported and used as an external module.

```
let bindRipples = () => {

  $('.ripple').on("click", event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    let $this = $(event.currentTarget)
    let $div = $('<div/>')
    let btnOffset = $this.offset()
    let xPos
    let yPos

    $div.addClass('ripple-effect')
    let $ripple = $(".ripple-effect")

    $ripple.css("height", $this.height())
    $ripple.css("width", $this.height())

    if(!$this.hasClass('ripple-fixed')) {
      xPos = event.pageX - btnOffset.left
      yPos = event.pageY - btnOffset.top

      $div.css({
        top: yPos - ($ripple.height()/2),
        left: xPos - ($ripple.width()/2),
        background: $this.data("ripple-color")
      })

    } else {
      xPos = event.clientX - $this.offset().left
      yPos = event.clientY - $this.offset().top + $('body').scrollTop()

      $div.css({
        background: $this.data("ripple-color"),
        top: yPos,
        left: xPos,
        position: 'absolute'
      })
    }
    $div.appendTo($this)

    window.setTimeout(() => {
      $div.remove();
    }, 4000)
  })
}

module.exports = bindRipples
```

Full credit to Craig Tuttle http://codepen.io/Craigtut/pen/dIfzv for making the script, I've just added small calculations to make it work on position fixed elements and have written it in ES6